# make command not found

Tags: makefile

I am running the following command to install a package in ubuntu 16.04 :

```
make install
```

In the output I have the following messages :

```
make: /usr/bin/sh: Command not found
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 127
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Systems with `/usr/bin/sh` are few and far between.  The de facto standard location for the shell is `/bin/sh`.

Something in that package's makefile must be setting the `SHELL` variable to `/usr/bin/sh`, which is wrong (it's generally a bad idea for a makefile to set `SHELL` at all, unless it needs a specific non-standard shell).

You can run `make SHELL=/bin/sh` to override this incorrect setting.

Comment: I have deleted `SHELL   = usr/bin/sh` rom the makefile. Now i have the following

Comment: `mehdi@mehdi-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC:~/pgapack-1.1.1$ make install`
Installing PGAPack . . .
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mehdi/pgapack-1.1.1/source'
cc -o ../lib/rs6000/binary.o -c -O  -I/home/mehdi/pgapack-1.1.1/include -Drs6000 -DWL=32 -DOPTIMIZE -DFAKE_MPI  binary.c
make[1]: /usr/bin/sh: Command not found
Makefile:53: recipe for target '../lib/rs6000/binary.o' failed
make[1]: *** [../lib/rs6000/binary.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mehdi/pgapack-1.1.1/source'
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
`